# How to achieve master- master replication between more than two postgresql databases?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, distributed-system, multi-master-replication, bucardo

I would like to be able to setup a master-master replication between more than two postgresql databases in the following way:

Consider three databases namely db_main, db_1, db_2. There is a bi-directional replication setup (swap sync maybe?, in Bucardo terms) between db_main and db1 and another between db_main and db_2. While db_1 and db_2 are not even directly connected, if I create table1 on db_1 and table2 on db_2 then both table1 and table2 should propagate to all three databases.

Is such a setup even possible? if yes how? what level of consistency? will the solution tolerate failures such as message loss due to network failure ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Offtopic. This is server/DB configuration, not programming. Try the DBA site.

Comment: Isn't is too soon to decide whether this is a programming problem? If no current tools/ technologies offer a solution to this (which is likely the case) then this is an open distributed replication problem right?

Comment: You can use BDR: http://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/bdr/ it supports up  48 master nodes Other options are SymmetricDS: http://www.symmetricds.org/ or HA-JDBC: https://ha-jdbc.github.io/

Comment: BDR requires connections between all nodes in a mesh. pglogical - the base of the successor/upgrade to BDR - won't, but it won't be ready for multimaster end-user use for a long time yet.